# Table-valued function runs fast, but slow from another function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, functions

*Disclaimer: I'm a senior sysadmin who's trying to help our development team speed up the production database. Our users are hurting, bad. Please don't shoot me for not being great with SQL*

The database server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 with the latest updates applied, running SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition with SP2+CU6. We also have a test server with the identical OS/SQL server installed. The production server has 96GB of RAM, where 76GB is free at this moment. The test server has 16GB of RAM, where 8GB is free at the moment. The production server is set to maximum use 90GB of RAM, while the test server is set to use maximum 12GB of RAM.

*Edit: I forgot to mention an important part.. the production database is mirrored offsite (async), while the test DB is not.*

We have the following functions.

**pl.get_overtime_from_pl** (Main function)

```
USE [Customapp]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [pl].[get_overtime_from_pl]
    (
      -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @dt SMALLDATETIME ,
      @officeId INT = 9999 ,
      @candId INT = 0 ,
      @onlyOverTime BIT = 0
    )
RETURNS @OvertimeRows TABLE
    (
      -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
      CandId INT ,
      CandName VARCHAR(100) ,
      OfficeName VARCHAR(60) ,
      OfficeId INT ,
      DateFrom CHAR(8) ,
      DateTo CHAR(8) ,
      ConsName VARCHAR(100) ,
      ConsId INT ,
      NormalTime DECIMAL(9, 2) ,
      OverTime DECIMAL(9, 2) ,
      TwoWeekTendency DECIMAL(9, 2) ,
      MonthTendency DECIMAL(9, 2) ,
      PeriodId VARCHAR(10) ,
      CompanyId INT
    )
AS 
    BEGIN   
        IF @candId > 0 
            SET @officeId = 9999
        IF @officeId = 0 
            SET @officeId = 9999

        DECLARE @dStart SMALLDATETIME ,
            @dEnd SMALLDATETIME ,
            @dStart2weekTendency SMALLDATETIME ,
            @dStartMonthTendency SMALLDATETIME
        SELECT  @dStart = dStart ,
                @dEnd = dEnd
        FROM    pl.get_overtime_periods_dates(GETDATE())



    --Find Start Date for this 2-week period
        SET @dStart2weekTendency = DATEADD(dd, -( DAY(@dEnd) - 1 ), @dEnd)
        IF DAY(@dEnd) >= 16 
            SET @dStart2weekTendency = DATEADD(dd, 15, @dStart2weekTendency)

    --Find start date for the current monthperiod
        SET @dStartMonthTendency = DATEADD(m, 11, @dStart) 

    --Bitwise
    -- 1 = OverTime
    -- 2 = Normal Time
    -- 3 = 1 or 2 - both
        DECLARE @iWageType INT
        IF @onlyOverTime = 1 
            SET @iWageType = 1
        ELSE 
            SET @iWageType = 3

        DECLARE @2weekPeriodFrom INT ,
            @monthPeriodFrom INT

        SELECT  @2weekPeriodFrom = MIN(yearperiod)
        FROM    pl.get_periods(@dStart2weekTendency, @dEnd) d

        SELECT  @monthPeriodFrom = MIN(yearperiod)
        FROM    pl.get_periods(@dStartMonthTendency, @dEnd) d




        INSERT  INTO @OvertimeRows
                SELECT  h.employeenumber CandId ,
                        ka.FNAME + ' ' + ka.SNAME CandName ,
                        a.NAME OfficeName ,
                        a.ID OfficeId ,
                        p.toUkeLonnFDT DateFrom ,
                        p.toUkeLonnTDT DateTo ,
                        ko.firstname + ' ' + ko.lastname ConsName ,
                        ko.id ConsId ,
                        SUM(h.NormalTime) NormalTime ,
                        SUM(OverTime) OverTime ,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN h.yearperiod >= @2weekPeriodFrom
                                 THEN OverTime
                                 ELSE 0
                            END) TwoWeekTendency ,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN h.yearperiod >= @monthPeriodFrom
                                 THEN OverTime
                                 ELSE 0
                            END) MonthTendency ,
                        h.yearperiod ,
                        h.companyid
                FROM    pl.get_worktime_from_pl(@dStart, @dEnd, @iWageType) h
                        INNER JOIN SalaryDatabase.dbo.Period p ON p.yearperiod = h.yearperiod
                                                              AND h.companyid = p.companyid
                        INNER JOIN ( SELECT employeenumber ,
                                            companyid ,
                                            CAST(homedept AS SMALLINT) homedept_int ,
                                            persNa
                                     FROM   SalaryDatabase.dbo.personal WITH ( NOLOCK )
                                     WHERE  ISNUMERIC(homedept) = 1
                                   ) k ON k.employeenumber = h.employeenumber
                                          AND k.companyid = h.companyid
                        INNER JOIN AVDELING a ON a.ID = k.homedept_int
                        INNER JOIN KANDIDAT ka ON h.employeenumber = ka.ID
                        INNER JOIN KONSULENT ko ON ko.ID = ka.KONSULENT_ID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.fn_get_groupoffices(@officeid) offices ON offices.id = a.id
                WHERE   ( @candId = 0
                          OR @candId = h.employeenumber
                        )
                GROUP BY h.employeenumber ,
                        ka.FNAME + ' ' + ka.SNAME ,
                        h.yearperiod ,
                        p.toUkeLonnFDT ,
                        p.toUkeLonnTDT ,
                        a.ID ,
                        a.NAME ,
                        ko.ID ,
                        ko.fornavn + ' ' + ko.etternavn ,
                        h.companyid
                ORDER BY h.employeenumber

        RETURN 
    END
```

**pl.get_overtime_periods_dates** (The previous function uses this)

```
USE [Customapp]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [pl].[get_overtime_periods_dates] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @dt smalldatetime
)
RETURNS 
@dates TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    dStart smalldatetime, 
    dEnd smalldatetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set
    declare @dStart smalldatetime, @dEnd smalldatetime
        --Find Start date for 12 month period
    if day(@dt)>=23 
    begin
        set @dEnd=dateadd(d,14,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @dt ), 0))
    end
    else if day(@dt)<9
    begin
        set @dEnd=dateadd(mm,-1, dateadd(d,14,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @dt ), 0)))
    end
    else
    begin
        set @dEnd=dateadd(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @dt  ), 0))
    end 
    set @dStart=dateadd(d,1,dateadd(yyyy,-1,@dEnd))

    insert into @dates
    values(@dStart, @dEnd)

    RETURN 
END
```

If I run this function directly as a query I get results within one second. At the same time I'm monitoring I/O on the server, and the tempdb is not touched.

If I call this function from a query, like this:

```
USE [Customapp]
GO
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '20131104', @office INT = 9999, @candidate INT = 0, @onlyovertime BIT = 1;
SELECT * FROM pl.get_overtime_from_pl (@date,@office,@candidate,@onlyovertime)
```

Then it suddenly takes 18 seconds to give me an result. I can see that the tempdb (or DB's, I've split them up into four files - one per core) are running through the roof with every IOPS we have available.

The *very* weird part here is that the function AND the query above runs within one second on our test server. I've looked at the server options, and they look identical. The only major difference is that we do nightly maintenance plans on the production server (reorganize index, update statistics).

I've been sitting in the SQL profiler trying to make sense out of this. I can see that SSMS is using slightly different connection settings than our custom application, namely "SET ARITHABORT OFF" while SSMS defaults to ARITHABORT ON. A few days ago I tried switching that back and forth, and suddenly both queries were fast (under 1 second). When I'm trying the same thing today, ARITHABORT doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever, the second query is *always* slow on our production server.

From my non-DBA perspective it seems like the function can use cached in-memory results, while the query cannot? I can't grasp why the second query is using the tempdb, while the function isn't..

What should I do next, other than begging our CTO to hire a DBA?

Comment: My first thought - parameter sniffing gone bad. Can you get the plans? In test only (don't do this in prod) - make sure you're the only one connecting to SQL Server, run `CHECKPOINT` then `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, then run the query in both fast and slow modes. Then `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle);` should return two rows.

Comment: What does pl.get_overtime_periods_dates look like?

Comment: @SimonRigharts Interesting, been reading about parameter sniffing and I'm pretty sure you're spot on - the values fed to this function changes nearly every time. I'll try the steps you provided.

Comment: @Zane Sorry, forgot that one. It's up in the question now.

Comment: Have you tried putting `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the queries? Have you tried changing from multi-statement table-valued functions to inline table-valued functions?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm going to ask our developers to re-write these horrible functions inside stored procedures instead, so that we can at least try a RECOMPILE option as a last effort.

Comment: I know this question is old and locked, but right off the bat I can tell your functions are not fully optimized because they are multi-statement table-valued functions rather than the much faster inline table-valued functions.

The goal when optimizing a table-valued function should be to include it all in 1 statement so SQL can optimize the execution plan. My guess is those IF statements are hurting optimization too. Here’s an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74f08/1/0

More: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/10/28/query-performance-and-multi-statement-table-valued-functions.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could create a tiny table:

```
CREATE TABLE OvertimePeriodsDates
(
dStart SMALLDATETIME,
dEnd   SMALLDATETIME
)
```

...then call `get_overtime_periods_dates()` once a day to populate this table.  Then just replace the call to `get_overtime_periods_dates()` with `OvertimePeriodsDates` in the start of `get_overtime_from_pl`.  In principal, this shouldn't change much of anything, but it may be enough to inspire a new query plan that doesn't take 18 seconds.

Comment: Not a bad idea, there's really no need to compute a 12-month period every single time the function is used. Do you think a SQL agent running the update should be enough?

Comment: Yep.  Or add a `LastModified` field to the `OvertimePeriodsDates` table, and have whatever process runs the sproc also update this table beforehand, if the `LastModified` field is not set to the current date.